# react native flatlist doesn't show updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm having a trouble in a flatlist that a button increments the value but doesn't show if I don't refresh or hit ctrl-s after incrementing value. ***Basically I cannot see the value change without pressing ctrl-s or going to another page and  returning to the same page.***

```
<FlatList 
    data={store}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
          <View style={styles.itemCountView}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.up}
              onPress={() => item.itemCount++}>
              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-drop-up" size={36} color="#ddd"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.itemCountText}>{item.itemCount}</Text>
          </View>
      )
    }}
  />
```

I can increment the value, if I save or go to another page and come back the value changes and i can see it but there must be a way to see it change.

**Any help is appreciated**

Comment: Add `extraData` props.

Comment: already tried it does't change anything

Answer (score 0):

As per the Documentation

#### extraData: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata

A marker property for telling the list to re-render (since it implements PureComponent). If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop, stick it here and treat it immutably.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach here:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';


const store = [{
  itemCount: 1
},
{
  itemCount: 2

},
{
  itemCount: 3

}]

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{
      flex: 1,
      padding: 140,
    }}>

    <FlatList 
      data={store}
      renderItem={({ item }) => ( <Item item={item}/> )}
    />    
    </View>

  );
}

 const Item = ({item})=> {
 const[count, setCount] = useState(item.itemCount);

     return (
         <View>
            <TouchableOpacity 
              style={{
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                padding: 10,
                margin: 10
              }}
              onPress={() => setCount(count+1)}>
            <Text style={{
              color: 'white'
            }}>{count}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
)
}
```

This will set the state for each item in the Flatlist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'r not saving the changes you doing, basically you need to update the the `store` variable each time you increment an item, something like:

```js
<FlatList 
    data={store}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
          <View style={styles.itemCountView}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.up}
              onPress={() =>  {
                     const newStoreData = [...store]
                     const itemIndex = newStoreData.findIndex(item)
                     const newItem = {...item,itemCount:item.itemCount ++}
                     newStoreData[itemIndex] = newItem
                     setStoreData(newStoreData) // state or redux?
} 

}>
              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-drop-up" size={36} color="#ddd"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.itemCountText}>{item.itemCount}</Text>
          </View>
      )
    }}
  />
```

Comment: I get an "Array.prototype.findIndex callback must be a function" error

Comment: yes sorry about this, it needs a call back where you check per example the id of your item until you find it, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp.